# Can't scroll to next answer

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm using the version 0.1.25 (03/11/2014) of the iOS app, and when looking at the answers to the question [Javascript RegExp as property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347669/javascript-regexp-as-property), I can only see the first answer (which fills the entire screen of the iPhone 5s).

[image: iPhone 5s screenshot]

Comment: There is new version released yesterday (0.1.25) please upgrade first and see if this still happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Oops, I meant March 12 (today).

Comment: Oh, cool. You can see the version by clicking the three horizontal lines in the top left then you'll see your name on top and the sites list, then hold it and drag down to reveal the version. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks! I wouldn't have thought to look there :)

Comment: Well, it's written in the iOS announcement but... :)

Comment: Hmm. I just restarted the app, and the problem seems to have gone away.

Comment: Weird, but still might be worth looking into.

Comment: @TimPietzcker did you by chance arrive at this answer directly from the feed or inbox? In other words, when you encountered this bug, the the app forward you directly to the answer tab (showing a yellow highlight)?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky: Yes, I think so.